# How to overlay a cell over two others in a CSS3 grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid, overlay

I need to be able to overlay an image in the center cell of a CSS3 grid over two other cells : one in the top-right corner and the other on the bottom left corner of the grid. Like this:

[image: Desired outcome]

So I figured I'd try to do it with a grid and *somehow* place the cells that have the corner borders underneath the central cell which contains the image. I made a 3x3 grid, placed corresponding borders and got this so far:

[image]

This is the HTML and CSS code:

```css
.informacion-imagen {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1px;
    grid-template-columns: 3rem auto 3rem;
}

#img-info {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: auto;
}

#corner-top-right {
    height: 3rem;
    border-top: 6px solid black;
    border-right: 6px solid black;
}

#corner-bot-left {
    height: 3rem;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
    border-left: 6px solid black;
```

```html
<div class="informacion-imagen">

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="corner-top-right"></div>

  <div></div>
  <div><img id="img-info" aria-hidden="true" src="assets/img/imagen-informacion.webp" loading="lazy"/></div>
  <div></div>

  <div id="corner-bot-left"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

</div>
```

From here on I have no idea how to address what I need to get the desired result. I've looked extensively on the web but this seems too specific. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason for having a 3 column grid other than as a means to get the corner borders showing?

Answer (score 2):

similar answer to [Positioning of a Absolute Element in relation to a responsive image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966803/positioning-of-a-absolute-element-in-relation-to-a-responsive-image/68966990#68966990)

`grid` alows you to set a few elements inside a single cell, alignement can be done simply via `margin`:

example

```css
div.corner {
  display: grid;/* default will be grid of a single column */
  width:max-content;
  margin:auto;
}

div>* {/* put everything into the same cell */
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

i {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}

.corner i:first-of-type {
  border-top: solid;
  border-right: solid;
  margin: 0 0 auto auto;
}

.corner i+i {
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-left: solid;
  margin: auto auto 0 0;
}

img {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="corner">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200" />
  <i></i><i></i>
  <!--Why not , are these alike icones ? -->
</div>
```

Comment: The way margin acts here makes `justify-self` and `align-self` look redundant. The fact that `margin-top: auto` push the element down, is it a grid feature, box alignment level3 or flexbox feature?

Comment: @user31782 it's not redundant. margin:auto was a feature since CSS2 (before flexbox or CSS grid). It was extended in the flexbox, CSS grid specification to consider the top and bottom. Also margin:auto is not the same as align-self. They can give the same result in most of the cases but they are different. auto margin is to distribute free space while the other is for alignment.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Where does MDN discuss `margin-top: auto` for grid? Secondly, other than `align-self: stretch` I can't think of a scenario where we can't just use `margin` in place of `justify/align - self` in grid.

Comment: @user31782 MDN is not my reference, Check this part of the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-margins. In CSS you can achieve the same thing using different ways so you may not find the need of margin auto but it's a feature different from align-self

Answer (score 2):

Use a a couple of pseudo-elements inside a single cell grid and align them as necessary. No additional HTML required.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  margin:.5em;
  display: inline-grid;
}

img {
  margin:.5em;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1;
}

div:before,
div:after{
  content:"";
  border-width:2px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent black;
  width:2em;
  height:2em;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1
}

div:after {
  justify-self:flex-end;
  align-self:flex-end;
    border-color: transparent black black transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: The corner borders are mirrored but I guess it's close enough

Answer (score 0):

Although using css grid to just chuck in L shapes around an image is an overkill, the technique I would use regardless of css grid is *css positioning* and  divs with borders(like you already have). There are other ways also like `:before` or `:after` pseudo selectors as well.

```css
.informacion-imagen {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1px;
    grid-template-columns: 3rem min-content 3rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

#img-info {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: auto;
}

#corner-top-right {
    height: 3rem;
    border-top: 6px solid black;
    border-right: 6px solid black;
    position: relative;
    left: calc(-100% + 15px);
    bottom: calc(-100% + 15px);
}

#corner-bot-left {
    height: 3rem;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
    border-left: 6px solid black;
    position: relative;
    right: calc(-100% + 15px);
    top: calc(-100% + 15px);
```

```html
<div class="informacion-imagen">

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="corner-top-right"></div>

  <div></div>
  <div><img id="img-info" aria-hidden="true" src="https://blog.cyclop.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/UNNAME1-977x720.jpg" loading="lazy"/></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="corner-bot-left"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

</div>
```

Take a note of the following addition css I used:

```
grid-template-columns: 3rem min-content 3rem;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with less code using 2 gradients as background

```css
img {
  --b:5px; /* adjust this */
  border:10px solid #0000; /* this */
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 0deg   at var(--b) calc(100% - var(--b)),#0000 90deg,#000 0) bottom left,
    conic-gradient(from 180deg at calc(100% - var(--b)) var(--b),#0000 90deg,#000 0) top right;
  background-size:60px 50px; /* and this */
  background-origin:border-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/200" >
```

Comment: Whoa! Very neat and code efficient. Thank you, I'll study it to see how it workds. I haven't seen conic-gradient before.