# Prevent image border from changing on toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My website uses some images that hide/show an overlay `onclick`.

I've built a custom border around these images uesing `.img-container::after` and `.img-container::before`

I can't work out why the border changes its height when the image overlay is toggled. My intention is for the border to always be displayed around the image which is static.

Please take a look at the example. Thanks for any advice.

```js
function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#PlanOverlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  place-items: relative;
  grid-template-areas: "inner-div";
}

/* Image wrap with corner borders */
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  place-items: absolute;
  grid-template-areas: "inner-div";
}

.img-container::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.img-container::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.img-info {
  position: absolute;
  grid-area: inner-div;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  grid-area: inner-div;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info-container">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000" onClick="toggleImage()" class="img-info" />
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000ff" id="PlanOverlay" onClick="toggleImage()" class="img-hidden" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` in `.img-hidden`.

Comment: By setting the image to `position: absolute` you remove it from the normal document flow. This results in your `div` getting a height of `0`. Hence the border moves

Comment: BAH! Thank you! Simple fix, can't belive I overlooked it *face-palm*

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967560/8620333 .. one element solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You just need fix `height` of your `img-container`:

```js
function toggleImage() {
  document.querySelector('#PlanOverlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "inner-div";
}

/* Image wrap with corner borders */
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "inner-div";
}

.img-container::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.img-container::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff8a8a;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.img-info {
  position: absolute;
  grid-area: inner-div;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  grid-area: inner-div;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info-container">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000" onClick="toggleImage()" class="img-info" />
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000ff" id="PlanOverlay" onClick="toggleImage()" class="img-hidden" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```